# How to add dynamic training job name to SageMaker training job executed within an AWS StateMachine described by CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine created with CDK (TypeScript). In this state machine I have a map state in which I run multiple ML model trainings with SageMaker, amount depends on the output of previous step, we have 2-5 datasets. I'm struggling with setting the training job name dynamically based on the output of the previous step. If I use static name even with only 1 training, I can't run the state machine multiple times because the training job already exists.

This is what I have tried with CDK

```
const training = new tasks.SageMakerCreateTrainingJob(
      this.stack,
      "SageMaker training job",
      {
         trainingJobName: "$.trainingJobName", // or static name like DemoTrainingJob
      ...
         InputDataConfig: [
           {
              channelName: "train",
              dataSource: {
                s3DataSource: {
                  s3Location: tasks.S3Location.fromJsonExpression("$.input"),
      ...
         hyperparameters: {
           "max_depth.$": "$.hyperparameters.max_depth",
```

s3DataSource and hyperparameters are shown only for reference as they work. Then, the previous step outputs trainingJobName like below (Data in TaskStateEntered for training job).

```
  "name": "SageMaker training job",
  "input": {
    "output": "s3://my-bucket/outputx",
    "input": "s3://my-bucket/inputx.csv",
    "hyperparameters": {
      "max_depth": "5"
    },
    "trainingJobName": "some-dynamic-name-YYYYMMDDHHiiSS"
  },
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  }
}
```

But as the input to SageMaker training (TaskScheduled) I see

```
 "resourceType": "sagemaker",
  "resource": "createTrainingJob",
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "parameters": {
    "TrainingJobName": "$.trainingJobName",
    "RoleArn": ...
```

And TrainingJobName is not interpolated from the input. S3 data is correctly interpolated (though differently expressed) and hyperparameter value. Naturally the job fails, because $.trainingJobName is not valid training job name. Static would fail too if I had used it before, but that is not ok, because it prevents using the state machine more than once.

I have seen this
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-cdk-examples/blob/master/cron-train/lambda-handler.py
where TrainingJob is started from Lambda where dynamic training job name can be easily set, but this should be possible also within a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

It must be set in the following way:

```
trainingJobName: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.trainingJobName")
```

or replace $.trainingJobName for whatever is your path to variable.